# Spring expression language (SpEL): parse String to int

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I've got a (`String`, obviously) property expressed in minutes that I want to convert to an `int` before I do some arithmetic and inject it into my Spring bean. Right now I have this SpEL expression:

```
#{T(java.lang.Integer).parseInt(myProperties['MIN_TIME']) * 60 * 1000}
```

where `myProperties` is a simple `java.util.Properties` bean.

Not that I'm particularly annoyed by this expression, but nevertheless: does the SpEL have a prettier, built-in way to parse strings into numeric values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Doesn't look like it, e.g. look at how the developers create them here: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-8716

A slightly shorter version could be

```
#{new Integer(myProperties['MIN_TIME']) * 60 * 1000}
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this for annotations?
**@Size((min = "#{new Integer(applicationProperties[size.min])}")
private int size;**

Comment: @luksmir I don't know. It's best to ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to use the util namespace to define a properties bean,
... 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
...
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd
...

```
<util:properties id="apiProperties"
    location="classpath:/api.properties" />
```

then use the alternate syntax for the properties bean

```
@Value("#{apiProperties['api.orders.pingFrequency']}")
private Integer pingFrequency;
```

The spring util properties bean generated by context will do the parse and conversion before assigning the value.